# find -exec option

Tags: bash, find

Say , i want to find some files and do chmod and do something with it with another command, eg

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec chmod 666 "{}" && cp "{}" /dst \;
```

it says

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

How do I properly use this `-exec` construct? I think the problem is with the "&&" ? I need to use this `&&` operator in case `chmod` fails
thank you

Answer (score 5):

Just use another `-exec` e.g.

```
find . -name \*.txt -exec chmod 666 {} \; -exec cp {} /dst/ \;
```

Comment: hi, i forgot to mention I want to use `&&` so that it won't copy if `chmod` fails

Comment: @user229426: you already get this behaviour implicitly with -exec

Answer (score 0):

Either write a little shell script and -exec that or use multiple -exec's.