# Call make in all subdirectories

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a directory structure such as:

```
home
|-- folder1
    |-- Makefile
    |-- code1.cpp
|-- folder2
    |-- Makefile
    |-- code2.cpp
|-- many more folders with Makefile and code inside
 .
 .
```

I want to call make on all the folders. How should I do about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: `find /home -type d -exec make ... {} \;`?

Comment: @fedorqui's suggestion is perfect, but you probably want a top level `Makefile` instead (particularly if it's a related project).

Comment: Sorry i don't really get you. Could you elaborate?

Comment: A top level Makefile would be perfect. But what do I put inside?

Comment: @yangshun, with my `find ...` command I suggest to use `find` to loop through all directories inside `/home` and do `make ...` in each one of them. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604750/find-exec-option

Comment: See [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

Comment: i get `make: Nothing to be done for 'folder1'.` and similar messages for the rest of the folders after trying the command by @fedorqui

Comment: Specifically [this section](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Eldar Abusalimov's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206500/compile-several-projects-with-makefile-but-stop-on-first-broken-build/11206700#11206700):

```
SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)

.PHONY : all $(SUBDIRS)
all : $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS) :
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

Comment: This also preserves any parallelism that you may have (it's `-jn` friendly). [`*/Makefile` might be a better wildcard BTW]